# Animating keyframes not working

Tags: animation, keyframes

So I had my rig and everything all set up and I played around with the animation and it was working fine, then I went to start on an actual proper animation and now it doesn't want to transition. Yes it's set at framerate 0 and yes I'm pressing play and selecting all when adding the keyframes but it also doesn't come up with the drop down menu to select locrotscale when pressing i, it just says that the keyframes have been added and that's it. I've fiddled with it for a while and it still doesn't want to transition

[image: thingy whingy]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bottom right in the keyframes section you've selected location, remove that you will get the menu when used I key on the keyboard

Comment: Kapai my dude, I was watching some type of video which mentioned to put that there but didn't think it did anything so didn't think much of it